# Cannot find my keyboard light directory!

Tags: directory

I'm trying to find my keyboard light directory to turn on the lights on the keyboard, but for some reasons I can't find it! If I try `/sys/class/leds/asus::kbd_backlight`  like other asus users do, I will open a black file. I just need to find the config file to edit the keyboard light, so far I couldn't find anything usefull...